# Minimum number of cylinders of Opposed Piston 2 stroke Diesel Engine

Tags: automotive-engineering

Would fewer than 3 cylinders work? Would 2 cylinder and even a single cylinder cause too much non-overlapping time between intakes so that the centrifugal impeller of the super/turbocharger starts to surge?

Comment: Would you exclude the use of a flywheel?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm primarily concerned with the ability of the impeller to not surge during long interruption of intake if you only have say a single cylinder whose intake stroke is only like 120 degree crankshaft angle.

Comment: You just need more volume in the intake plenum. Big marine diesels have a separate turbo compressor and manifold for each cylinder, and they run about 600 rpm. So no pressure to make the charge air cooler small - it can be plenty big enough to do it's job efficiently.

Comment: @PhilSweet is that true? How many turbocharger would there be if I had say an inline 14?

Comment: erm, 14 - The big Wartsila. And the blowers are each about the size of a bedroom. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFiymRwkR-GHew7PQkEs2kX-y1U2YEZQeCuA&usqp=CAU